# Using Maps for DML record collections instead of Lists

Tags: apex, visualforce

How can I insert selected records from a table(this contains multiple objects) using map collection instead of list?

As a newbie in Apex development, I am currently having my training using Salesforce Trailhead and other sites. These help me a lot in understanding how Apex and Visualforce really work together.

But in this specific case, it seems that I need the help of more experienced developers. I tried looking through various resources (researches, forums, blogs), especially Trailhead, but there's no luck, unfortunately. Any help would be great.

Comment: Hi qwerty, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you. SFSE is a Q&A forum where we look to help each other by asking and answering questions about real problems or errors with our code. Posting requests to write code for you generally get closed.

Answer (score 2):

The insert DML operation adds one or more sObjects, such as individual accounts or contacts, to your organization’s data.

Let's assume that you have Map of contacts:

```
map<Id,Contact> contactMapToUpdate = new map <Id,Contact>();
//You could insert it like this:
if (!contactMapToUpdate.isEmpty())
    update contactMapToUpdate.values();
```

Comment: Read [Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm)
try to understand what is collection why it's used. My favourite is [Visualforce_in_Practice](https://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf)
If you don't have programming background, go through [JavaScript tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/)
If you have time read 'Thinking in Java' by Bruce Eckel.